# Display all sub category but one

Tags: categories

How would I display all the sub category but one? I tried `is_category('myslug')` then return in the post loop but it wont work.

my code in the post loop

```
if(is_category('myslug')){
    return;
}
```

Stills return all the sub category even the one with slug `myslug`

Comment: Not entirely clear what you mean. From the codex on is_category: "This Conditional Tag checks if a Category archive page is being displayed". 

Are you trying to display a list of sub-category names or are you displaying an archive page of sub-categories?

Comment: I'm displaying a list of posts that are in a category and its sub categories, but there are posts from one category that I dont want to display

Comment: Can you post some code from the page or template you're working on? It sounds like you'll need to alter the query for that page, but I just want to see what your code looks like now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to exclude certain subcategories in a category archive page, try put the following code in your functions.php:

```
function exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_category( 'myslug' ) && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'cat', '-1,-1347' ); //Add your excluded subcategories ids
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'exclude_category' );
```

If it's not the case, we need your code to see the whole picture.